# Linux scripting to get count of string pattern from folders and subfolders

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a folder and it has folders and sub folders.

This folders and subfolders contains files like

```
input_abc.txt 

input_def.txt
```

pattern1 is 'RCA'
pattern2 is 'RSA'

Folder strusture:

Folder
  -subfolder
     -subfolder
       :input_abc.txt
       :input_def.txt

I have to get count of string "pattern1" from file having filename `input_abc.txt` and I have to get the count of string "pattern2" from file having filename `input_def.txt` within these subfolders.

How can I get the count of pattern1 along with file name `input_abc.txt`
and pattern 2 along with file name `input_def.txt` from these folder and subfolders in Linux.

Comment: Do you have a sample tree structure and pattern you are looking for?

Comment: I have updated the question with pattern and folder structure

Comment: So inside `input_abc.txt` is the string `pattern1`, and you want to scan all the files in `subfolder` to see how many times `pattern1` appears?

Comment: Yes input_abc.txt contains pattern 1(RCA) and input_xyz.txt contains pattern 2 (RSA) so I want all the files having file name "_abc.txt" and count of pattern1 and all the files having file name "_xyz" and count of pattern 2

Comment: `q()(echo $(find "$1" -name "$3"|xargs grep -Fho "$2"|wc -l) "$3"); q Folder RCA input_abc.txt; q Folder RSA input_def.txt`

Comment: How to export the result of this into text file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need `find -iname NAME -exec grep -inr PATTERN {} \+`:

```
➜  tree
.
├── b
│   ├── abc.txt
│   └── def.txt
└── c
    ├── abc.txt
    ├── def.txt
    └── ghi.txt

2 directories, 5 files

➜  for f in {b,c}/*; do printf "$f -- "; cat $f; done
b/abc.txt -- patt1
b/def.txt -- patt2
c/abc.txt -- patt1
c/def.txt -- patt2
c/ghi.txt -- patt1

➜  find . -iname abc.txt -exec grep -inr PATT1 {} \+
./c/abc.txt:1:patt1
./b/abc.txt:1:patt1
```

What happens here?

`find` finds all files with the given name (this is a glob, not a regex): `-i` stands for ignore case, `-exec` runs the following command (`grep ...`) on the files found (represented by `{}`).

Please note the `\+` which means to pass all the found files to a single grep (use `\;` if you want to pass those files each one to a different `grep` - would not show the file names).

As you can see `patt1` is in `b/abc.txt`, `c/abc.txt` and `c/ghi.txt`, but the latter is ignored by `find` (name not matching) and `grep` will not run on that file.

Comment: Pattern1 is to be searched only  in file having name _abc.

Answer (score 0):

We can define a function `srch` as:

```
srch()(
  grep -nirc "${2}" * | grep "_${1}\.txt" | cut -f 2 -d":" | paste -sd+ - | bc > output_${1}_${2}.txt
)
```

Then call it with:

```
srch abc RCA;
srch def RSA
```

Basically, `grep` will count the times the string appears in each file, then filter out the files that don't match the suffix you want (`abc`,`def`,etc.).  Then it will use `cut` to get the counts and add them up with `bc` and redirect to a file `output_*.txt`